# Crash when the video texture Spark AR runs on device

Tags: spark-ar-studio

We are trying to build a Video Texture filter using Spark AR.

- When you point AR camera at a specific logo, the plane tracker will identify the object and starts a video on the screen.
- We referred this link to build it: `[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TUmjepXSna8][1]`
- It works on the default player on the Spark Studio but when we run it on the device, the Spark AR app crashes.
- Not able to find any logs for the crash.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Same issue. I also tried with a video from my server. Works perfect on Spark Ar but neither working on mirroring nor export